# Jenkins Options missing while entering a private key; "from a file on jenkins master" and "From the Jenkins master ~/.ssh"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have set up a new Jenkins Server and copied the Jobs and plugins from the old Jenkins Server, but stragely there are 2 Options missing while entering a private key for the global User/Account. The Options are "from a file on jenkins master" and "From the Jenkins master ~/.ssh".
I doubt that there is some plugin missing, as I have copied all the plugins from old Server. Any clue will be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These options was removed due to [security reasons](https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2018-06-25/#SECURITY-440) since version 1.14 of SSH Credentials Plugin:

> **SSH Credentials Plugin no longer supports SSH credentials from files on the Jenkins master file system, neither user-specified file paths nor ~/.ssh**. Existing SSH credentials of these kinds are migrated to "directly entered" SSH credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation!

Comment: So what do we do instead

Comment: @funkybro, the only current option is to enter (paste) private key directly to input field in Jenkins interface.